# How to select option from object?

Tags: angularjs

I have object `$cities = {'name' : 'Bamber', 'id' : 3}`

And select list:

```
<select ng-selected="selectedCountry == item.id" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in countries"></select>
```

Where `selectedCountry` is equal 2. But `ng-selected` does not work for me

Comment: Can you give example? `ng-model` with object `$cities`?

Comment: I tried `ng-model="obj"` where `$scope.obj = {'name' : 'Bamber', 'id' : 3}`

Comment: Yes, I told about this in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `ng-model` AND `track by item.id`

```
<select ng-model="country" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in countries track by item.id"></select>
```

And the controller :

```
$scope.countries = [
   {id: 2, name: 'france'},
   {id: 3, name: 'hongrie'}
];

$scope.country = $scope.countries[0];
```

The jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Fieldset/y414hdkb/

The problem is you had to select your item by the index and not the "real" country id, but in your controller you can write your own function that return the index from the county id

**EDIT:**

With this code, you can find the index from the country id :)

```
var defaultCountryId = 2;
var defaultCountryIndex = $scope.countries.map(function(country){return country.id;}).indexOf(defaultCountryId);
$scope.country = $scope.countries[defaultCountryIndex];
```

Comment: But if I want to select item with `id = 3`?

Comment: Also I need that `value` will be `id` from object,  not index